# Swagger / OpenAPI: link to tag with encoded spaces

Tags: swagger, github-flavored-markdown, openapi

I have my Swagger API definition with a tag:

```
    "tags" : [
    {"name": "Api Keys",
    ...
```

I would like to have a link to this tag below in a description, so I use GFM syntax encoding the space as following:

```
[Api Keys](#tag/Api%20Keys)
```

However, the link does not work. If the tag has not spaces, then it works perfectly. Is there a way I can use tags with spaces in its name and have a link to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not state what tool you are using to view your Swagger/OpenAPI definition, but if you are using Swagger UI, try replacing the spaces in the link to the tag with underscores.

Comment: Thank you four your response. In fact, I am using ReDoc and, as a workaround, I was already using hyphens, but since the tags are displayed in the final view as menu items, I would like to avoid them (and also underscores).

Comment: Ah, redoc is nice. I meant only replace the spaces with hyphens in the link *target*, not the text, e.g.

    [Api Keys](#section/Api-Keys)

The replacement of the spaces by hyphens is done automatically by redoc when creating the anchors.